# Docker не запускает контейнер php-cli

Tags: php, docker

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста почему не запускается контейнер?

проект на laravel

nginx, php-fpm и тд тут все ок

```html
version: '3'
services:
    freelara-nginx:
        build:
            context: ./docker
            dockerfile: nginx.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
            - ./docker/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
        depends_on:
            - freelara-php-fpm
        ports:
            - "8080:443"
    freelara-php-fpm:
        build:
            context: ./docker
            dockerfile: php-fpm.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
        depends_on:
            - freelara-mysql
    freelara-php-cli:
        build:
            context: ./docker
            dockerfile: php-cli.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
            - composer:/root/.composer/cache
        depends_on:
            - freelara-mysql    

volumes:    
    composer:
```

```html
FROM php:7.3-cli

RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.7.2 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer --quiet

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

WORKDIR /app
```

```html
FROM php:7.3-fpm

RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /app
```

```html
FROM nginx:1.15-alpine

ADD ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /app
```

```html
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /app/public;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /docs {
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass freelara-php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь нужно понимать что такое работающий контейнер. 
Работающий контейнер это ничто иное как работающий процесс, т.е. активный работающий процесс.

Ну смотрите. Сейчас поймете зачем я делаю вот такие манипуляции:

`docker pull php:7.3-fpm`

`docker inspect php:7.3-fpm`

вывожу информацию об образе и нахожу вот это

```
"Cmd": [
            "php-fpm"
        ]
```

т.е. при запуске контейнера по-умолчанию запускается php-fpm, но важно понимать что php-fpm висит как процесс и за счет этого живет и сам контейнер.

Дабы убедиться - [находим Dockerfile данной сборки](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/affbdaf1386876560e287cd7708fafe2a4d246eb/7.3/buster/fpm/Dockerfile)

и в самом низу видим что действительно мы запускаем php-fpm.

Однако я могу запустить контейнер изменяя точку входа

`docker run -ti --entrypoint /bin/bash php:7.3-fpm`

и вот я попадаю в контейнер.

и прям тут мы можем выполнить `php-fpm` и увидим что действительно процесс работает

```
[28-Jan-2020 09:55:17] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 12
[28-Jan-2020 09:55:17] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

Теперь давайте посмотрим что же касается php-cli
Чтоб сократить время - вот ссылка на [7.3-cli образ](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/affbdaf1386876560e287cd7708fafe2a4d246eb/7.3/buster/cli/Dockerfile)
и мы видим что по-умолчанию запускается `php -a`  при старте контейнера. Это интерактивная консоль, однако ежели вы запустите данный контейнер `docker run php:7.3-cli`  то вы увидите в выводе

```
Interactive shell
```

и все, контейнер перестал работать. Все дело в том что при `php -a` не запускается ни какой демон, а в силу того что вы запустили контейнер без ключей -ti то и к контейнеру не подключается `STDIN` и процесс php shell как открывается так сразу и закрывается.

Резюмируя я хочу сказать что на самом деле у вас запускается `php-cli` контейнер строго в соответствии вашего docker-compose файла, вы  даже чтобы убедиться можете посмотреть `docker ps -a` и увидите остановленный контейнер `php-cli` (по крайней мере должны), но он останавливается т.к. останавливается пораждающий его процесс и это стандартное поведение контейнеров.

---

Дополню ответ по поводу запуска консольных комманд.

Говорить о том что контейнер для консольных комманд должден быть все время запущен, скорее всего не приходится. По сути вам нужно запустить контейнер по мере надобности и при выходе из него его потушить. Соответственно так как у нас (у вас) cli контейнер живет во время работы какого либо процесса, а в данном конкретном случае это будет процесс bash, то при разлогинивании контейнер остановится. Соответственно при повторном запуске поднимется ровным счетом тот же контейнер, осталось только правильно все это описать.

Основную сложность всегда представляло из себя именно то, как связать друг с другом контейнеры, чтоб они друг друга видели и взаимодействовали. Если раньше (сейчас deprecated) использовалсь `link` в docker-compose и возможно при вынесении какого либо сервиса в другой docker-compose файл было проблематично, то сейчас это не составляет проблем используя network. Теперь от теории к практике.

Чтобы сделал я.

Я бы создал cli-compose.yml где описал бы отдельно сервис `freelara-php-cli` и соответственно вынес бы его из `docker-compose.yml` существующего

Нужно добавить network c одинаковым именем во все сервисы. (и в новый файл тоже)

```
version: '3.5'
  services:
    freelara-nginx:
      build:
        context: ./docker
        dockerfile: nginx.docker
      volumes:
        - ./:/app
        - ./docker/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
      depends_on:
        - freelara-php-fpm
      ports:
        - "8080:443"
      networks:
        - mynetwork
    freelara-php-fpm:
      build:
        context: ./docker
        dockerfile: php-fpm.docker
      volumes:
        - ./:/app
      depends_on:
        - freelara-mysql
      networks:
        - mynetwork
volumes:
  composer:

networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: freelara-network
    driver: bridge
```

Ну и соответственно файл `cli-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  freelara-php-cli:
    build:
        context: ./docker
        dockerfile: php-cli.docker
    volumes:
        - ./:/app
        - composer:/root/.composer/cache
        networks:
            - mynetwork
volumes:    
    composer:
networks:
    mynetwork:
        name: freelara-network
        driver: bridge
```

Собственно дело осталось за малым - нужно запустить все это хозяйство. 
Сервисы из docker-compose.yml вы запускаете как обычно - `docker-compose up -d` , а вот сервис консольный вы запускаете в два этапа, во первых вам нужно собрать сервис

`docker-compose -f ./cli-compose.yml build`

И наконец для того чтобы вы запустили bash или любую другую команду

`docker-compose -f ./cli-compose.yml run freelara-php-cli bash`

где вы видите имя сервиса который запускается и команду, которую вы хотите запустить. Можете например

`docker-compose -f ./cli-compose.yml run freelara-php-cli php -r 'phpinfo();'`

И зная вот все это дело, вы можете сделать alias и запускать в нужный момент любую консольную комманду через алиас, что то типа

`dcli ls -lah` где dcli - алиас для docker-compose -f ... и так далее, но это возможно лишнее.

Надеюсь я достаточно понятно описал происходящее. Старался как мог. :)

Comment: Благодарю за подробное описание, через данную команду docker run -ti --entrypoint /bin/bash php:7.3-cli заходит в контейнер все ок, но не могу понять как мне теперь сделать как раньше чтобы контейнер freelara-php-cli был запущенный и я мог запускать bash? На 7.2 php и version: '2' раньше все ок работало, но вот после настроек нужная мне команда для разработки не срабатывает docker-compose exec freelara-php-cli bash

Comment: @lagavu exec выполняет команду в запущенном контейнере. Вам можно поступить несколькими способами. Самый простой это выполнять свои команды через freelapa-php-fpm. Запускаете ровным счетом то же самое что и через cli и это должно работать. 
Есть вариант запускать это более правильно, с моей точки зрения используя все таки cli . Напишу по приезду домой.

Comment: Спасибо! хорошо буду ожидать. Необходимо чтобы я в запущенном контейнере php-cli как раньше через exec заходил в bash

Comment: с проблемой разобрался спасибо, что откликнулись!

Comment: @lagavu дополнил ответ, возможно вам покажется интересным предложеный мною вариант 

И если помог, можете не стесняясь поставить галочу что ответ вам подходит :) Спасибо :)